# How to autogenerate a Panache entity

Tags: jpa, quarkus

Is it possible to auto generate Panache entities from existing database tables in eclipse/any other environment.?
I am trying out quarkus, and have a database with a number of tables and would like to auto generate the entity code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Panache entities are JPA entities with an `extends PanacheEntity` or `extends PanacheEntityBase` at the type decaration site.

You can generate your JPA entities, both Eclipse and ItelliJ IDEA have plugins for that, then add the extends clause.

Be carefull that if you extends `PanacheEntity` you should use the default id strategy that it provides (an autogenerated Long id), so better extends `PanacheEntityBase` if you generates from an existing schema.

Panache also provides a repository approach that can be useful if you don't want to update your entity after generation.